# Excel formula to find the ROW number of a previous blank cell in a particular column

Tags: excel-formula

[Need Row number of the blank cell (C8) on (D11)-Green cell. Starting the search from "C11"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqSAm.png)

[image]

Comment: Explain your question.

Answer (score 0):

In `D4`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(AND(B5<>"",C4<>""),MATCH("zz",B$1:B4),"")
```

[image]